# Unknown Set: White spaceship? with clear blue canopy

Tags: set-identification

Do you know which set this is? It's incomplete, and I would like to get the instructions. It looks a bit like a spaceship...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Hey *Mc5*,

Set #*76028 Darkseid Invasion*.

Build instructions *[here](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions/search?initialsearch=76028#?text=76028)*.

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Awesome! Many thanks Rin Rio-Oki!